# how to set position of UIViewController title?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a customized UIViewController and I need to change the position of title.

How can I do that?

Is there any attribute to set?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what effect you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every view controller has a `navigationItem` property. It's type is `UINavigationItem`. This class has a `titleView` property. Instead of saying:

```
self.title = @"Some Title";
```

in your view controller, you can do:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = someCustomView;
```

The trick in your case is to create a `UIView` class that contains a `UILabel` positioned how you want. There are limits to this solution but since you didn't provide any details about what you actually wish to achieve, this is the best solution without further information.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it.

If you want that type of control over the user interface, then you cannot use the built in system controls.